# Question from book, reviewing for test

Tags: triangles, math-history

The question is as written: "Now given a rope hanging from the top of a pole.  The end lying on the ground is 3 chi long.  When tightly stretched it is 8 chi from the bottom of the pole.  Let x represent the height of the pole.  Tell:  how long is the rope and how high is the pole?"

I am told to find the equation for the problem, but I am having difficulty making sense of the problem itself. What I have so far is this...

-The length of the pole is equal to x.
-The length from the base of the pole to where the rope touches the ground when it is stretched out is equal to 8 chi.

-And the hypotenuse of the triangle is equal to x+3 as it is understood that if the rope is left alone, it is the length of the pole with 3 chi added to it.

What I have done so far is use the pythagorean theorem to get the equation: (x^2) + (8^2) = (x+3)^2 but after that is where I get lost in trying to find the equation or how to simplify this equation for the length of the rope. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe your setup is correct, although I did find the wording of the question to be a little confusing. Given $x^2+8^2=(x+3)^2$, we can expand $(x+3)^2 = (x+3)(x+3) = x^2+3x+3x+9 = x^2 + 6x+9$, allowing us to say $x^2+8^2 = x^2+6x+9$. Do you see where to take things from here?

Comment: yes, I expanded that part of the equation and got it down to: (x^2) + (8^2) = (x^2) + 6x + 9. I then simplified 8^2 to 64 and subtracted 9 from both sides and had the equation down to (x^2) + 55 = (x^2) + 6x. After that, I got stumped and tried to find another way around this problem.

Comment: Subtract $x^2$ from both sides of the equation.

Comment: I did that before as well and simplified the equation down to 55 = 6x, and I divided 6 from both sides and got 55/6 = x or 9.1666667 = x. But the following question asks for the equation that represents the problem and Im given multiple answers for it, but none of them make any sense to the problem itself. Im given the following equations: A) (3^2) + (8^2) = (x^2)  B) (x^2) + 9 = 64  C) (1/2) * x * 3 = 8  and D) (x+3)^2 = (8^2)

Comment: And I've tried to apply all of these equations to the problem itself but none of them make sense in how they are formed based on the information from the problem and using the pythagorean theorem, unless theres a unique way to simply the problem and Im just missing it entirely.